# Make yanking pipe into an external program

Tags: os-clipboard

Is it possible to set up an external program as my clipboard?
I'd like vim to pipe into it whenever I yank something.

Comment: What version of `vim` are you using? I've been using Neovim for long I don't know how current vim versions are handling this, but Neovim _only_ handles the OS clipboard through an external provider, so all you would have to do is replace the shell scripts it relies on with one of your choosing. See `:help clipboard`...

Comment: I'm using 7.4.52.  I like that design decision in noevim. Perphaps I'll give it a whirl.  I'm asking because I'm otherwise using a clipboard script that uses either a user-specific tempfile or the X clipboard depending on whether I'm running vim under X or not, and it'd be nice if I could make vim use it.

Comment: Ripping out all the system clipboard stuff and leaving it entirely up to system utilities to integrate with the clipboard has easily been one of the most controversial changes made in Neovim, but I agree the separation of concerns makes it easier to configure to my liking across different systems. That being said I'm sure your use case is configurable in vim as well. You might want to [edit] some of those details into your question to make it easier to answer properly.